# Adding memory to deployed JVM

Tags: java, batch-file, memory

I have an issue with one of the users of the java application of ours.
In certain situation for a large data select, that particular user gets "Out of Memory" errors.  The problem is ONLY for this user and, of course, we will deal with this for subsequent releases, but for now is it possible to allocate more memory on that user's machine to run this application?  User access the application by a shortcut on her desktop.  Shortcut points to a shared network location from where all of the users run the program in similar way.  So, Is it possible to somehow specify memory parameter from the shortcut - I think it's like giving java memory heap size from a command line, but what is the syntax for doing this?

Thanks

**Editing in response to those who lowered my rating:**

- This question was NOT about increasing heap size, contrary to what respondents thought.
  I do mention, that the program starts with the batch file, that is on the network.  That batch file calls the command

  java -Xms -Xmx -DsomeOtherOptions

I was asking, how can I (if I can) without touching that batch file, in a shortcut to it send the new memory options. 
I am not looking for an answer on how to run java program

```
java -Xms<initial heap size> -Xmx<maximum heap size>
```

But looking for what to put in the windows properties of the shortcut to that batch file. (if it is possible)
Thanks

Comment: I was asking, how can I (if I can) without touching that batch file, in a shortcut to it, send the new memory options. I am not looking for an answer on how to run java program

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`java -Xms<initial heap size> -Xmx<maximum heap size>`

For eg: To increase the heap size by 256MB use `-Xmx256M`

Refer **[1]** http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above you need to specify

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

you can increase this size as required.